# loop through a portion of a knockout observable array

Tags: for-loop, knockout.js

Is it possible to only loop through a portion of a knockout observable array while data-binding to a html page, similar to a traditional for loop?

```
(i = 0 ; i< 10; i ++)
```

instead of

```
data-bind foreach : myKnockoutArray
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do simple trick .. for example

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ItemsArray">
<!-- ko if: $index() < 10 -->
     <div data-bind="text: someProperty"></div>
 <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the observableArray's slice method which works the same as JS native slice method. Its described in the [observable arrays page](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myKnockoutArray.slice(0,10)">
    <!-- loop body -->
</div>
```